# Jquery modal box close button styling issue with custom theme

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I have recently created a custom theme for Jquery UI to use on my site. I have also added a modal box form for the user to upload a file. Everything works great. The small issue I have is with the appearance of the close button. The X appears outside of the button itself. See the image below. I am guessing it has to do with conflicting styles but I am not sure where or what is causing the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

This is the only thing I can find. When I inspect the elelment in my browser I see this:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close"></button>
```

The actual code for displaying the form looks like this:

```
    $(function() 
    { 
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          width: 400,
          height: 300,     
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "Add File": function() 
        {
        $('form#addFile').submit();
              },
              Cancel: function() 
              {
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           $('#uploadFile').val( "" );
              }
         },
         close: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
    });

    $( "#new-file" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

After lots of playing around with the style editor in the web console I was able to identify a style definition in jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css as the culprit:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close span {
    display: block;
    margin: 1px;
```

Specifically the margin: 1px. Not sure why but deleting this line fixed the issue. Thanks to everyone who commented!

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: any chance of setting up a fiddle? this looks like a margin problem

Comment: Post the relevant CSS for this